# Rows containing Null values in all columns are returned when Max(date) aggregate function is used in sql query

Tags: mysql, sql, inner-join

I am using Mysql database and having a problem with inner join. I am using aggregate function max(dn.on_date) in the query to select only recent date rows.
this is working fine when rows are found with matching criteria but when where clause condition becomes false it 1 row is returned containing NULL value for all columns. I want to ignore that row to be returned as result.

Table structures are as follows : 
[view table structure and relation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PwWrZ.png)

**my query is like** :

> SELECT d.first_name, d.last_name, d.mobile, dn.don_amount as amount, 
>   max(dn.on_date) as on_date 
>   FROM donors d 
>   inner join donation dn 
>   on d.mobile = dn.don_id 
>   WHERE LOWER(first_name) LIKE LOWER('dinesh%') order by d.mobile asc LIMIT 0,4

**Unwanted Results is returned like this** :
[view results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/chjZJ.png)

I want that it should not return anything when where condition is not matched

**I have tried like this but it doesn't work and result is same as previous**

> SELECT d.first_name, d.last_name, d.mobile, dn.don_amount as amount, 
>   max(dn.on_date) as on_date 
>   FROM donors d 
>   inner join donation dn 
>   on d.mobile = dn.don_id 
>   WHERE d.mobile IS NOT NULL AND LOWER(first_name) LIKE LOWER('dinesh%') order by d.mobile asc LIMIT 0,4

Comment: Aggregate functions wont work without group by clause.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you used aggregate function but not seen group by in your query

```
SELECT d.first_name, d.last_name, d.mobile, dn.don_amount as amount, max(dn.on_date) as on_date 
FROM donors d 
inner join donation dn on d.mobile = dn.don_id 
WHERE LOWER(first_name) LIKE 'dinesh%'
group by d.first_name, d.last_name, d.mobile, dn.don_amount
order by d.mobile asc 
LIMIT 0,4
```

Comment: Thanks @Zaynul this worked. But why this is necessary to use Group BY.

Comment: @DINESHKumarSISODIYA please read about aggregate function, it works for group of data that's why you  have to put that btw  if it works mark it accepted